# Incorrect computation in Knight and Fu (2000)?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, lasso, asymptotics, derivative

I'm currently reading Knight and Fu's 2000 paper on the asymptotics of "Bridge" estimators with a particular focus on LASSO as a special case. In the proof of theorem 2, they make the claim that under their assumption that $\lambda_n/\sqrt n \to \lambda_0 \geq 0$ and $\gamma > 1$, we have
$$\lambda_n\sum_{j=1}^p\left[|\beta_j + u_j / \sqrt n|^\gamma - |\beta_j|^\gamma\right] \to \lambda_0 \sum_{j=1}^p u_j \mathrm{sgn}(\beta_j) |\beta_j|^{\gamma - 1}$$
But we should have
\begin{align*}\lim_{n\to\infty} \lambda_n\sum_{j=1}^p\left[|\beta_j + u_j / \sqrt n|^\gamma - |\beta_j|^\gamma\right] &= \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\lambda_n}{\sqrt n}\sum_{j=1}^pu_j \frac{|\beta_j + u_j / \sqrt n|^\gamma - |\beta_j|^\gamma}{u_j/\sqrt n} \\
& =\lambda_0 \sum_{j=1}^p \gamma u_j\mathrm{sgn}(\beta_j)|\beta_j|^{\gamma - 1}\end{align*}
by taking the derivative of $f(x) = |x|^\gamma$, which is differentiable when $\gamma > 1$, so it seems they are off by a factor of $\gamma$. Their later derivations appear to not hinge on constants, since they are doing asymptotics, so it's a minor error, but I wanted to double check to make sure I am not missing something here.

Comment: Your derivation is convincing.

Comment: I just wasted a ton of time trying to figure this out, and I reached the same conclusion as you.